# How to ensure a consistent backup?

Tags: centos, backup, centos7, mongodb, xfs

I'm running MongoDB 4.0 with the WiredTiger storage engine under CentOS 7. The data files are held on a mounted XFS volume.

I can't use my hosting provider's backup service because it doesn't support XFS volumes. This means I need to take snapshots some other way and copy them over to a redundant file system that does have backups enabled.

I've read [this article](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/backup-with-filesystem-snapshots/#back-up-and-restore-using-lvm-on-linux) which gives various options for taking the snapshots, but it doesn't go into detail about how to ensure a [Valid Database at the Time of Snapshot](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/backup-with-filesystem-snapshots/#valid-database-at-the-time-of-snapshot).

In addition to the LVM method described I've also looked at `xfsdump` and have even considered `rsync` (because the data comprises many small files). But regardless of the snapshot/copy method, how do I ensure that the backup is in a consistent state?

Comment: For the record - I'm not on AWS, but LVM looks like the way to go. I [wrote a bit on the Linode community forum](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/18178/how-can-i-back-up-an-unsupported-disk-format#answer-68799) if anyone else is looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

Only one way to ensure a consistent backup, restore it and spot check the data. Naturally this requires procedures to *take* a consistent backup first...

---

Databases are always being written to. Filesystem snapshot methods require taking an atomic snapshot of the volume across **all** of its LUNs. Only storage system layer or LVM layer can do this. (Not copying files.)

Consistency behaviors are specific to the DBMS used. From [that link](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/backup-with-filesystem-snapshots/#valid-database-at-the-time-of-snapshot):

> For the WiredTiger storage engine, the data files reflect a consistent
>   state as of the last checkpoint. Checkpoints occur with every 2 GB of
>   data or every minute.

These checkpoints are persisted to disk with the usual I/O system calls (probably `pwrite()` and `fsync()`). If the storage system has a volatile cache and it goes down, writes may be lost.

Journal allows you to take a snapshot at any time, inconsistencies will be fixed during journal replay. However, if your journal volume is different from your data volume, or you don't journal, read the bit about [write lock before taking a snapshot](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/backup-with-filesystem-snapshots/#back-up-instances-with-journal-files-on-separate-volume-or-without-journaling).

In summary you need:

- atomic snapshots across all LUNs
- journal
- a storage system where acknowledged writes are actually committed

Comment: Thanks. I am journaling, and it's on the same volume.